# Index not creating in kibana for mongodb + logstash +elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to visualize the mongodb data in kibana using logstash configuration.Below is my configuration.I'm getting  some outputs in terminal and it is looping forever. I couldn't see any index created by the name mentioned in the config file and if the index was generated also don't have any data on it. Saying no results to match in the discover tab.How to make the configuration to visualize the data in kibana?

```
 input {
            mongodb {
            uri => "mongodb+srv:@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
            placeholder_db_dir => "C:/logstash-mongodb"
            placeholder_db_name => "logstash1_sqlite.db"
            collection => "logs"
            batch_size => 1
            
            
            }
    }
    filter {
    
    }
    output {
            stdout {
                    codec => rubydebug
            }
            elasticsearch {
                    action => "index"
                    index => "ayesha_logs"
                    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            }
    }
```

[image]

http://localhost:9200/ayesha_logs/_search?pretty

[image]

Terminal logs:
D, [2020-10-01T08:11:45.717000 #2372] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | range-api-test-cluster-shard-00-02.icqif.azure.mongodb.net:27017 req:259 conn:1:1 sconn:231839 | coexistence-poc.listCollections | STARTED | {"listCollections"=>1, "cursor"=>{}, "nameOnly"=>true, "$db"=>"coexistence-poc", "$clusterTime"=>{"clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x32598cb2 @increment=1, @seconds=1601532700>, "signature"=>{"hash"=><BSON::Binary:0x2622 type=generic data=0xfaf25a8d85...
D, [2020-10-01T08:11:45.755000 #2372] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | range-api-test-cluster-shard-00-02.icqif.azure.mongodb.net:27017 req:259 | coexistence-poc.listCollections | SUCCEEDED | 0.038s
D, [2020-10-01T08:11:50.801000 #2372] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | range-api-test-cluster-shard-00-02.icqif.azure.mongodb.net:27017 req:260 conn:1:1 sconn:231839 | coexistence-poc.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"coexistence-pinfobackfill-logs", "filter"=>{"_id"=>{"$gt"=>BSON::ObjectId('5f71f009b6b9115861d379d8')}}, "limit"=>50, "$db"=>"coexistence-poc", "$clusterTime"=>{"clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x32598cb2 @increment=1, @seconds=1601532700>, ...
D, [2020-10-01T08:11:50.843000 #2372] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | range-api-test-cluster-shard-00-02.icqif.azure.mongodb.net:27017 req:260 | coexistence-poc.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.042s
D, [2020-10-01T08:11:50.859000 #2372] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | range-api-test-cluster-shard-00-02.icqif.azure.mongodb.net:27017 req:261 conn:1:1 sconn:231839 | coexistence-poc.listCollections | STARTED | {"listCollections"=>1, "cursor"=>{}, "nameOnly"=>true, "$db"=>"coexistence-poc", "$clusterTime"=>{"clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x32598cb2 @increment=1, @seconds=1601532700>, "signature"=>{"hash"=><BSON::Binary:0x2622 type=generic data=0xfaf25a8d85...
D, [2020-10-01T08:11:50.906000 #2372] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | range-api-test-cluster-shard-00-02.icqif.azure.mongodb.net:27017 req:261 | coexistence-poc.listCollections | SUCCEEDED | 0.047s

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create your Kibana's index pattern ?
If not, just go to Menu > stack managment > Kibana > Index pattern

click on [image]

And follow the steps.
[image]

You will then be able to use you index in Discover or visualization tabs.

Comment: I'm able to create the index but while visualizing i couldn't see any data on it. Please see the screenshot which have added now.

Comment: 1 -  in the dev tools , query you index with GET myindex/_count to verify that it's well populated. 
2- do the same with a _search ordered by @timestamp desc an check the last date of insert. 3- verify your time range in kibana

Comment: GET ayesha_logs/_count :{
  "count" : 0,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}

Comment: You don't have no data in your index. so the problem is not on the kibana side. The issue is at the logstash side. I did not seen the problem in the logs you post, are you sure the your mongodb query is finding documents ?

Comment: I could see the one of mongodb document id in terminal.coexistence-poc.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"coexistence-pinfobackfill-logs", "filter"=>{"_id"=>{"$gt"=>BSON::ObjectId('5f71f009b6b9115861d379d8')}}, "limit"=>50, "$db"=>"coexistence-poc", "$clusterTime"=>{"clusterTime"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x32598cb2 @increment=1, @seconds=1601532700>,

Comment: Am i missing any configuration in logstash conf file?or is there any other way to sync mongodb docs to elasticsearch?